# Swift - iCarousel library

Tags: swift

I need to implement iCarousel library in Swift but I could not find the one which is written purely in Swift (I do not want to use objective C library with Bridge header).

Can you please let me know such library or any other alternative one?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution, ZCarousel is written purely in Swift.

Here is the link:

https://libraries.io/github/richzertuche/ZCarousel

I hope it will save time for some people who are looking for carousel library in swift.

Thanks!